# How to show one autocomplete depending on another autocomplete in primefaces ?

Tags: autocomplete, primefaces

I am using two autocomplete components. First one shows all car companies (ex: honda,ford...) and another autocomplete has to show the car models depending on selected car company of first autocomplete. (if I select honda in first autocomplete, second autocomplete should show only honda car models (ex:city,civic ...)).

Comment: _What have you tried so far?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest example I could come up with:

```
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete value="#{bean.make}"
        completeMethod="#{bean.completeMake}">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" />
    </p:autoComplete>
    <p:autoComplete value="#{bean.model}"
        completeMethod="#{bean.completeModel}" />
</h:form>
```

The `p:ajax` is necessary to call the setter of the make.

And the backing bean (getters/setters) omitted:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean
{
    private List<String> makes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, List<String>> makeModelMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    private String make, model;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        makes.add("Honda");
        List<String> hondaModels = new ArrayList<String>();
        hondaModels.add("Civic");
        hondaModels.add("City");
        makeModelMap.put("Honda", hondaModels);

        makes.add("Ford");
        List<String> fordModels = new ArrayList<String>();
        fordModels.add("T");
        fordModels.add("Focus");
        makeModelMap.put("Ford", fordModels);
    }

    public List<String> completeMake(String query)
    {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : makes)
        {
            if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
            {
                results.add(s);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> completeModel(String query)
    {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : makeModelMap.get(make))
        {
            if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
            {
                results.add(s);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```